# extract ID from byte[]

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, mask

I read `byte[]` from socket as `Param_Code` which includes ID.

```
byte[] cbuf = new byte[4];
socketReader.read(cbuf, 0, 4);
int Param_Code = byteArrayToIntBI(cbuf, 0);

public static int byteArrayToIntBI(byte[] b, int offset) {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 3; i > -1; i--) {
            int shift = (i) * 8;
            value += (b[i + offset] & 0x000000FF) << shift;
        }
    return value;
   }
```

• Option 1: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds only to the ID

• Option 2: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds to 0x40000000 + the ID

• Option 3: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds to 0x80000000 + the ID

My question is, How can i get ID from Param_code considering above options.

Comment: yes, what does "sometimes"mean?  or if 0<param_code(pc)<0x400.., pc=id; if 0x40000..<pc<0x800.. pc=0x4000...+id, and if pc>0x800..., pc=0x800..+id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using ByteBuffer?

```
byte[] cbuf = new byte[4];
socketReader.read(cbuf, 0, 4);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(cbuf);
int Param_Code = buffer.getInt();
```

Comment: I need conversion to little-endian and also extracting ID from Param_Code considering above 3 options?

Comment: You need to tell us in which cases the ID can take the the values you mentioned.

Comment: Tanks Tudor. Your solution is more compact. I gonna use it.

My question is, How can i get ID from Param_code considering below options.

• Option 1: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds only to the ID

• Option 2: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds to 0x40000000 + the ID

• Option 3: Sometimes the Param_code corresponds to 0x80000000 + the ID

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes"? How do you know if it's option 1 or 2 or 3?

Comment: I read 4byte from socket and By sometimes i means dynamically from socket comes out. i have no control over this value.